# ob_start and php.ini output_buffering

Tags: php

Is `ob_start` necessary when the `output_buffering` is turned on in the php.ini file?

If `output_buffering` is turned on, then PHP will buffer almost the entire page, so what's the point in creating yet another buffer using `ob_start`?

Comment: Use ob_start for things like extracting an associative array

Comment: @true PHP is already buffering that entire page, so wouldn't ob_start be redundant?

Comment: no it would provide another layer

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically enable output buffering with `ob_start()` for when you write your own output buffer functions.